# Math with different width variables and casting

Tags: c

Consider the following code snippet:

```
// The assigned numbers are random and not relevant
uint16_t val = 2;
uint32_t sum = 4;

sum += val; // point 1

sum /= val; // point 2
```

1. In this operation, is the val automatically cast to `uint32_t`? If not, what is faster- casting it or leaving as `uint16_t`?
2. In this operation, is the val automatically cast to `uint32_t`? If not, what is faster- casting it or leaving as `uint16_t`?

Assume the architecture is 16-bit.

Comment: 1. yes and no difference, 2. yes and no difference. The only change that might speedup things a very very tiny bit would be to change `val` to `uint32_t`, because then it does not have to zero the higher 2 bytes. Often this happens automatically, so even this might not speedup anything.

Comment: I have added an important factor I have forgot to mention in the beginning- the architecture is 16-bit. How does it play out then?

Comment: See the conversion rules: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion

Comment: The architecture doesn't really matter. The C Standard states that the operands will be converted to a common type by means of the "usual arithmetic conversions".

Comment: Exactly the same comment. The operands must have same type, so the smaller one gets converted to the bigger one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases, the value of `val` is automatically converted to the larger type `uint32_t`. The precise behavior depends on the actual size of `int`.

- If type `int` has 15 value bits, the `val` is converted to `uint32_t`, preserving the alue, the addition and division are performed using `uint32_t` arithmetics, which operates modulo 2<sup>32</sup> and the result is stored into `sum`.
- If type `int` has between 16 and 31 value bits, `val` is first promoted to `int`, preserving its value, then the promoted value is converted to `uint32_t`, again preserving the value because it is positive, and the operation completes as described above.
- If type `int` has more than 31 value bits, both `sum` and `val` are promoted to `int`, preserving the values, the addition and division is performed using `int` signed arithmetics, and the result is converted to `uint32_t`, modulo 2<sup>32</sup>, for storage into `sum`.

For the above example values, the result is the same in all cases, but for the example below, the behavior is undefined on a hypothetical architecture where `int` would have 32 value bits:

```
uint16_t val = 2;
uint32_t sum = 0xffffffff;

sum += val; // signed arithmetic overflow if type `int` has 33 bits
```

These implicit promotions and conversions are not *cast* operations, you could add explicit casts such as `sum += (uint32_t)val;` but the behavior would be exactly the same and would have no impact on performance.

If the compiler can determine the value of `val` at compile time, it will likely compile the expression `sum /= val;` into a right shift or a multiplication to avoid a costly division. Dividing an unsigned value by a power of 2 is a cheap right shift operation, if the value is signed and potentially negative, the shift must be adjusted. For other non-zero dividends, a multiplication by 2<sup>k</sup>/val into a larger type is used.

Comment: On a 16-bit architecture, adding a 16 bit value to a 32 bit variable could be (a little) faster than adding 2 32-bit values because it requires fewer memory reads. The division is the main issue: you should definitely keep the dividend variable as a `uint16_t`. You can examine the object code generated for different options on https://www.godbolt.org